# beforeAll/beforeEach afterAll/afterEach should be inside `describe`?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am bit confused. Should `beforeAll`/`beforeEach`/`afterAll`/`afterEach` be inside `describe` or outside?

Example:

```js
describe('unamed', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
     //
  })
})
```

Vs

```js
beforeAll(async () => {
  //
})

describe('unamed', () => {
  //
})
```

Which is correct? Or doesn't matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a before/after function at the top level of the file, it will apply to all the tests in the file. If you have them inside a `describe` scope, they only apply to the tests under that `describe` scope.

Comment: If is out off escope, only applies to the current test file, right? Not to other test files

Comment: Does having both these functions at the top level and inside a describe makes one to take over the other ?

Comment: They both fire: first the top level beforeEach, then the `describe`'s beforeEach, then the test, then the `describe`'s afterEach, then the top level afterEach.